# regex which should check string contains specified word

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a regex which should check does string contains word 'Page' and after it any number
This is code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "12/15/14  7:01:44    Page   10 ";
    String str2 = "12/15/14  7:01:44    Page    9 ";
    System.out.println(containsPage(str2));
}



private static boolean containsPage(String str) {
    String regExp = "^.*Page[ ]{1,}[0-9].$";
    return Pattern.matches(regExp, str); 
}
```

Result: str1: false, str2:true

Can you help me what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the regex to the following:

```
String regExp = "^.*Page[ ]{1,}[0-9]+.$";
```

so that it matches one or more digits (hence the `[0-9]+`).

You also don't need the boundary matchers (`^` and `$`) since `Pattern#matches` would match the entire input string; and `[ ]{1,}` is equivalent to `[ ]+`:

```
String regExp = ".*Page +[0-9]+.";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
String regExp = "^.*Page[ ]{1,}[0-9]+.$";  //or \\d+
                                    ↑
```

`[0-9]` matches 9 in the second example, and `.` matches the space.

In the first example, `[0-9]` matches 1, `.` matches 0 and remained space isn't matched. Note that `^` and `$` are not really needed here.

Your regex can be simplified to:

```
String regExp = ".*Page\\s+\\d+.";
```